# Is onSensorChanged supposed to work in an Android virtual device (emulator)?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sensors

I am testing some sample code to learn Android.

Is `onSensorChanged` supposed to work in an Android virtual device (emulator)?

My `onSensorChanged` (for `TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE`) is never called.

In the reference
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html#onSensorChanged(android.hardware.SensorEvent) there is no information about the emulator.

Comment: Of course it isn't supposed to work.

Comment: @NickT "of course"? Is there any official reference? I can't find it. For example the emulator could generate a fake temperature signal...

Comment: did u try this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377690/setting-temperature-through-emulator

Comment: @Nadosh thank you very much! Now I understand how to change temperature via the emulator... even if my code still not working and I haven't found the "Hardware section" that JustinDanielson is talking about in his answer...