# How to report the details of my Android development environment?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Let say I have a code sample working on an AVD emulator, how can I report the details of my Android development environment for giving a reference accompanying the code?

Is there any Android API for reporting this kind of info?

The information I am talking about are, for example:
I have downloaded the adt-bundle-linux-x86_64, has it any version?
The details of my AVD,
etc.

Comment: I think you need to understand Android better.  I could develop an app in Eclipse.  I could develop the same app in ACME Corps Thunderbird Brain Boiling Soup Dragon special code gizmo and Android would not know the difference.  The only things Android knows about your app is what's inside the APK.  Oh, and what colour underwear you have on.

Comment: @Simon Is there any particular reference, related to the question, you can suggest to me in order to understand better Android?

Comment: I was not being very serious was I? Sorry.  What I meant is that the APK does not contain any information about your development environment (not strictly true but it would be an enormous hack to figure out) and there is nothing in the Android API to help you.  Perhaps it's best to ask "why do you want this".  Perhaps there is a better method?

Comment: @Simon OK, see for example this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377690/setting-temperature-through-emulator the code of the OP seems very similar (OK, not perfectly equal...) to the one I posted in my answer, but my code works on my emulator, the OP's code does not work on her emulator. If the two sample codes were equal, would it be possible two different behaviors in two different emulators?

Comment: Yes it's very possible.  For example, if the API versions were different.  I would also expect possible differences between AVDs with the same API level running on Windows vs Mac vs Linux since the emulators are different.  I say possible because that would be a bug since I am assuming that the emulators are cross-compiled but who knows?